# How to check which database exists and use it in the function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Given different machines with sql server. All of them have the same databases. The only difference between these db's is their name. It could be two names, let's say 'DB1' and 'DB2'.

I need to check, which name is used on the given machine and create a function over it. The function is pretty big, it has at least 50 spots where the name of the DB is needed.

I was trying to do something like

```
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(20)
SET @dbName = ISNULL(DB_ID('DB1'), 'DB2');

SELECT * FROM @dbName.dbo.testtable;
```

But it does not work. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the names of the databases in advance, or are they potentially variable?

Comment: @Paul Williams. I do. It will be either DB1 or DB2. No other possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't work.  With only two possible database you may be better off with an `if`:

```
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(20)
SET @dbName = CASE WHEN DB_ID('DB1') IS NULL THEN 'DB2' ELSE 'DB1' END;

IF @dbName = 'DB1' 
    SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.testtable;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.testtable;
```

If you want to run ALL future queries in that scope against that database then dynamically run a `USE` statement instead:

```
IF @dbName = 'DB1' 
    USE DB1;
ELSE
    USE DB2;
```

Comment: So basically, if I have 100 references to one of these db's, I have to use that if-else for each reference. Correct?

Comment: @DzmitrySevkovich if all of the queries are in the same scope than you can use a `USE` statement to change the database - see my edit.

Comment: @D Stanley unfortunately, it gave me an error: a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.

Comment: Can you choose the database before running the procedure?  The procedure should then run using that database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(20)
SET @dbName = 'DB2'

IF DB_ID('DB1') IS NOT NULL
    SET @dbName = 'DB1'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @dbName + N'.dbo.testtable'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this using the `DB_ID` function:

```
IF DB_ID('DB1') IS NOT NULL
PRINT 'exists'
```

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(20)
SET @db = CASE WHEN DB_ID('DB1') IS NULL 
          THEN 'DB2' 
          ELSE 'DB1'
          END;

IF @db = 'DB1' 
    SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.testtable;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.testtable;
```

Comment: I actually used it. But I don't need to just check if it exists, but I want to use the name of existing db.

Comment: @DzmitrySevkovich:- I have updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: `ISNULL(DB_ID('DB1'), 'DB2')` will try and cast the string `DB2` to an int if `DB1` does not exist.

Comment: @MartinSmith:- Sir I didnt get that very clearly. Am I missing something. It would be great if you can edit my answer if that is wrong! :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi: if you try to run that query, you get the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'DB2' to data type smallint."

Comment: @RahulTripathi - The most obvious way to fix it is in D Stanley's answer already.

Comment: @MartinSmith:- Yes I have done that. But D Stanley was more quick. But I have updated my answer as well! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @dbName = 'DataBaseName'


IF db_id(@dbName) is not null

   BEGIN    
       SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N'.[dbo].[TableName]'   
   END

ELSE

  BEGIN
    SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(db2Name) + N'.[dbo].[TableName]'
  END 

EXECUTE sp_Executesql @Sql
```